# Group files and pipe to awk command

Tags: linux, bash, awk, xargs

I have files in a directory; they are named using YYYY_MM_DD:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 497186 Apr 21 13:17 2012_03_25
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 490558 Apr 21 13:17 2012_03_26
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 488797 Apr 21 13:17 2012_03_27
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 316290 Apr 21 13:17 2012_03_28
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 490081 Apr 21 13:17 2012_03_29
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 486621 Apr 21 13:17 2012_03_30
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 490904 Apr 21 13:17 2012_03_31
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 491788 Apr 21 13:17 2012_04_01
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 488630 Apr 21 13:17 2012_04_02
```

The first column within the file is a number, and I am using the following `awk` command to take an average of that first column.

```
awk -F, '{ x += $1 } END { print x/NR }' MyFile
```

Using the same command i can pass two files to awk to get the total average of both files as a whole.

```
awk -F, '{ x += $1 } END { print x/NR }' File1 File2
```

What I want to do is this...

I want to get all the files in my directory, and group them per month, then pass all the files for the month to the awk command.

So as per the same data, there are 7 files in March, I would want all 7 files to be passed to my `awk` command like this:

```
awk -F, '{ x += $1 } END { print x/NR }' File1 File2 File3 File4 File5 File6 File7
```

Then likewise for April's set.

Comment: How are you going to decide which months should be processed?  Would it be a command invocation something like `monthly_stats 2012-03 2012-04`?  Or would you need to scan all the files in the directory to see what months are represented in order to process them all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you wanting to somehow accomplish this with awk alone, or can you use file globbing?  For example:

```
awk -F, '{ #Do stuff }' 2012_03_[0-3][0-9]
```

will get all the March files.

You could also use `2012_03*` but that's less specific in its globbing pattern than the above one.

***Edit***

You can use a shell script like this:

```
DIR="/tmp/tmp"
for month in $(find "$DIR" -maxdepth 1 -type f | sed 's/.*\/\([0-9]\{4\}_[0-9]\{2\}\).*/\1/' | sort -u); do
  awk -F, '#dostuff' "$DIR/${month}"_[0-3][0-9] > output/dir/SUM_"${month}"
done
```

As always, there are a few caveats.  Files with spaces will break it.  You'll get errors if there are files that don't conform to the YYYY_MM_DD format in the directory, but it shouldn't affect performance.  Let me know if those constraints are not acceptable and I'll think on it a little more.

Comment: This will be ok, but i want to just point to the directory and have it work out how many months there are and process each month as a batch if you understand me. There are multiple years in here too so 2012_04_11 and 2011_04_11 may exist.

Comment: yeh should be fine, I'll have a play when i have some time and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: I would have upvoted the first part of your answer, however the added part uses `for ... in $(ls)` (twice, no less). Also, the output of `ls` will include the directory, which you fail to strip - so in your example, `year` will equal "path". And speaking of "less specific", you could use `2012_03_[0-3][0-9]` to be a *little* more specific.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson All good points.  I was a little careless before.  See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Perl you could do it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
$dir = shift || ".";
opendir(DIR, $dir);
@files=grep (/\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2}/, readdir(DIR));

foreach $file (@files)
{
    ($year_month) = $file =~ /(\d{4}_\d{2})/;
    open(FILE, "<$dir/$file");
    while($col = <FILE>)
    {
        $col =~ s/^(\d*)/\1/;
        if($col)
        {
            $hash{"$year_month"}{"count"}++;
            $hash{"$year_month"}{"sum"} += $col;
        }
    }
}

foreach $year_month (keys %hash)
{
    $avg = $hash{"$year_month"}{"sum"} / $hash{"$year_month"}{"count"};
    print "$year_month : $avg\n";
}
```

Can probably do it shorter, but this way you have a nice hash data structure in case you want to calculate it differently later. Call like:

```
script.pl /path/to/dir
```

EDIT: bug: forgot to add directory to path